# ajax server call getting timeout even after adding timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout

I have a server ajax call which is returning timeout even the server response back.

If server response back in 2-4 mins then ajax going into success
If server responds after 4 mins then no action happening in ajax call

I have also tried with timeout in ajax call but it didn't work.

Even added http timeout in configs.

```
$.ajax({
        url: urlAction,
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: {
            data : "parmeters"            
        },
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // after 15 mins this is throwing timeout error
        },
        timeout: 900000
        });

    }
```

But i can see server methods are returning the correct json.

Comment: can you show us what you tried ?

Comment: Add some code to see how can we help please

Comment: @wasanga7 i have updated the ajax request.

Comment: @madalinivascu update the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

you can abort the xhr after the timeout

```
 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   XMLHttpRequest.abort();
 },
```